# Correlation between different sentiment lexicons

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis, lexicon

I am trying to build a sentiment lexicon for a specific domain. At the moment I need to compute the correlation of the sentiment scores derived from my method with one of the standard already existing lexicons. First, can anybody help me and tell me what measure is best to use for computing the correlation and which library implements it? Second, is there any paper that has assessed the correlation (similarity) between various already existing lexicons?

Thank you in advance.